# Check if usercontrol is within Window Bounds

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a project that requires the ability to drag a user control (hosted within a grid) around the screen. This works just fine with the below code:

```
void MyUserControl_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ct = (CompositeTransform) RenderTransform ?? new CompositeTransform {CenterX = 0.5, CenterY = 0.5};
        ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        ct.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

The issue is that the user control can be dragged all the way out of the screen area. To prevent this, I tried the example shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationdelta.aspx

Unfortunately, it uses **containingRect.Contains(shapeBounds)** whereas in windows 8, we are expected to replace shapeBounds(this is a rect) with a Point. I am not sure on how to work with this.

So the question is how can we ensure that a user control or any UIElement cannot be dragged out of the Window.Current.Bounds area in windows 8 store app?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** More details on the xaml structure:

The mainpage contains a Grid with horizontal and vertical alignment set to stretch. Usercontrols are added to this grid as required. Each usercontrol has a parent grid that contains 3 different views (fullscreen, window and small). The views are shown based on the user's choice. The drag behavior must be applied only when the window grid is shown. So we have this

```
<Grid> <!-- this is the parent grid on mainpage with horizontal and vertical alignment to stretch-->
   <Grid> <!-- this is the usercontrol's main grid (added to above grid via code). This grid must be draggable if the below grid is window -->
         <Grid /> <!-- this is one of the child grids that is shown based on user's choice (fullscreen, window or small view).-->
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I dont have much choice in changing the layout. Using the above ManipulationDelta event in the usercontrol (which is enabled/disabled based on the child grid shown), I am able to get the drag behavior, but the control can go out of window bounds. So is there any way we can add the below FlickBehavior in WinRTXamlToolkit through code instead of xaml OR enable/disable the behavior based on some condition?

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <views:HeavyFlickBehavior />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Where is your usercontrol ? in canvas ?

Comment: It is inside a grid, but can be moved to a canvas if using a grid is a problem.

Comment: I think you have to manually check whether the usercontrol's edge is near to bound or not using `TransformToVisual` and `TransformPoint`

Comment: You have the source code so you can easily add or remove that behavior. You could simply clear or set ManipulationMode on the control to enable/disable the behavior. BTW - don't use `HeavyFlickBehavior` - that is a stress test class in WinRT XAML Toolkit used to test for memory leaks. Each instance uses 100MB of RAM! :)

Comment: Thanks Filip! Dunno how I didnt think about enabling/disabling the manipulation mode. One last thing if you dont mind - is there a way to attach behaviors through code instead of xaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the [`FlickBehavior`](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c540adbd6952821a351d9ffa4d1d99#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Behaviors/FlickBehavior.cs) in WinRT XAML Toolkit for an example of how to achieve that with a parent `Canvas` and `Canvas.Top/Left` properties instead of `RenderTransform`, assuming the `Canvas` defines your bounds.

Here's an abstract:

```
private void OnAssociatedObjectManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _startPosition = new Point(
        Canvas.GetLeft(this.AssociatedObject),
        Canvas.GetTop(this.AssociatedObject));
}

private void OnAssociatedObjectManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs manipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs)
{
    var dx = manipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs.Cumulative.Translation.X;
    var dy = manipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs.Cumulative.Translation.Y;

    var x = _startPosition.X + dx;
    var y = _startPosition.Y + dy;

    if (manipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs.IsInertial)
    {
        while (x < 0 ||
               x > _canvas.ActualWidth - this.AssociatedObject.ActualWidth)
        {
            if (x < 0)
                x = -x;
            if (x > _canvas.ActualWidth - this.AssociatedObject.ActualWidth)
                x = 2 *
                    (_canvas.ActualWidth - this.AssociatedObject.ActualWidth) -
                    x;
        }

        while (y < 0 ||
               y > _canvas.ActualHeight - this.AssociatedObject.ActualHeight)
        {
            if (y < 0)
                y = -y;
            if (y > _canvas.ActualHeight - this.AssociatedObject.ActualHeight)
                y = 2 * (_canvas.ActualHeight - this.AssociatedObject.ActualHeight) -
                    y;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (x < 0)
            x = 0;
        if (x > _canvas.ActualWidth - this.AssociatedObject.ActualWidth)
            x = _canvas.ActualWidth - this.AssociatedObject.ActualWidth;
        if (y < 0)
            y = 0;
        if (y > _canvas.ActualHeight - this.AssociatedObject.ActualHeight)
            y = _canvas.ActualHeight - this.AssociatedObject.ActualHeight;
    }

    Canvas.SetLeft(this.AssociatedObject, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(this.AssociatedObject, y);
}
```

Comment: Hi Filip, thanks for the detailed response. I will test it later today and revert back. Would it be possible to implement the same using RenderTransform and Grid as the container?

Comment: Yes, assuming your transform only updates X/Y properties you would simply update its X/Y instead of Canvas.Left/Top. The only problem might be if your dragged item is bigger than the container as that could cause clipping. I don't think my code even factors it in though, so it could still crash or hang. Just make sure to set your child control's HorizontalAlignment to Left, VerticalAlignment to Top and Margin to 0.

Comment: Hi Filip, Tried the above solution and it works fine if the parent is canvas with a child uielement. But I have a slightly more difficult problem. I have edited my question to explain better.